# How to search a string and replace a string in text file?

Tags: c

I'm facing a problem in replacing a string in a text file. The function below is able to find the string. I want to replace the text but I'm not sure how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
void searchchangeword() {
    //Related to file status 

    char buffer[1024]= {0};
    FILE *stream;
    char *Ptr,*Ptr2;
    int len;
    int pos;
    stream = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if(NULL == stream)
         printf("fopen failed");

    while(1) {
        fscanf(stream,"%s",buffer);
        if((strcmp(buffer,"LogLevel")== 0)) {
            pos = ftell(stream);
            memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
            fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stream);
            // Here i get the word i want to replace
            fscanf(stream,"%s",buffer);
            break;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
    // closing the Opening file
    if((Ptr2 = strchr(buffer,'\n')) != NULL)
        *Ptr2 = 0;
    Ptr = strtok(buffer, " ");
    // Suppose Ptr contains John 
    // How can i replace it with James at the same position
    //-- Changing string logic ??
}
```

Comment: Usually you open two files, one for reading and another for writing. After all the changes are done, delete the input file and rename the output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you the idea, not the code.

An easy way is to:

- load the file in a string(char *text) (use fopen, malloc, readf, fseek, ftell)
- Make another file as a destination file (use fopen), and open as write
- Make two more strings(string1,string2) and load in string1 the file
  until pos(the position of the word to replace)(using text) then load
  in string2 from pos + the lenght of the string you wanted to replace
  until the end of the file(using text).So string1 will be until the
  "LogLevel" and string2 after the "LogLevel".(If "LogLevel" the string to be replaced)
- Then write the first string (string1) in the destination file the
  replacement word and the second string (string2) (all in the
  destination file)
- Close all the files (use fclose)
- remove the original file ("input.txt")(use remove)
- rename the destination file as the original one "input.txt" in your
  case (use rename)

Thats what i think in my silly brain. Maybe that was helpfull.